# Eigenvectors of nilpotent $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence

> Let $N$ be a $3\times3 $ matrix such that
>
> 1. $N^2 = O_3$, then how many linearly independent eigenvectors will $N$ have?
> 2. $N^3 = O_3$, then how many linearly independent eigenvectors will $N$ have?

I think if $N^2=O_3$ then there will only one eigenvector and if $N^3=O_3$ then it can have 1 or 2 linearly independent eigenvectors depending on whether $N^2= O_3$ or $N^2\ne O_3$.

Am I right?

Comment: What about $N = 0$?

Comment: I think if $N=0$ then in that case every non zero  vector will be an eigen vector. so we should assume $N\ne0$

Comment: If $N^2=0$ $N$ has two linearly independent eigenvectors if $N\neq 0$ and $3$ if $N=0$.

Answer (score 4):

1) From $N^2=0$ we have $\operatorname{Im}N\subset \ker N$ and from the rank-nullity theorem we get $\dim\ker N=2$ and $\dim\operatorname{Im}N=1$ (assuming $N\ne0$). So since $\ker N= E_0(N)$ the eigenspace associated to $0$ so $N$ has two linearly independent eigenvectors associated to $0$.

2)  Now  if $N^2\ne0$ then there is $e\in E$ such that $N^2e\ne0$. We prove that $(N^2e,N e)$ are linearly independent so it's basis of $\operatorname{Im}N$ and then $\dim \ker N=1$. Can you take it from here to achieve the proof?

Comment: can I use that if $N^2\ne0$ then there will be a jordan block of $3$ order as $N^3\ne0$ will be minimal polynomial, from Jordan block can we say that there is $1$ eigen vector ?